# Mongodb crashing all the time

Tags: mongoid, mongodb

I'm running a single instance mongodb, and the database is crashing all the time.
Anyone knows if this problem is related with running in a single instance?

Tue Aug  9 09:02:59 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60194 #129526
Tue Aug  9 09:17:04 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=517 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 32-bit

** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
**       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
**       with --dur, the limit is lower

Tue Aug  9 09:17:04 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Aug  9 09:17:04 [initandlisten] git version: 433bbaa14aaba6860da15bd4de8edf600f56501b
Tue Aug  9 09:17:04 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux bs-linux32.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:39:36 EST 2008 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_37

---

old lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock.  probably means unclean shutdown
recommend removing file and running --repair
see: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for more information

---

Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen std::exception: old lock file, terminating
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 dbexit: 
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Aug  9 09:17:05 dbexit: really exiting now

Comment: Add relevant information. "It is crashing" is hardly enough to make any sort of informed comment.

Answer (score 2):

Two Possible Problems:

Look at **ulimit -a** to see how many open files you're allowed.  Each TCP connection counts as an open file.  likewise the actual files open.  Set this to a high number and see if the crashing stops.

**Also, check the value of max processes**, it should be at least 4096 or 8192 for a busy server (we've got ours at 32768).  Most of these processes are tracking connections, so they are idle most of the time.  But, even on an unsharded system, you can get close to those limits.

## To check actual open files:

```
lsof -p <pidnumber>
```

## to check actual processes:

```
ps axo pid,ppid,rss,vsz,nlwp,cmd | egrep mongod
```

then look a the nlwp column.

***To fix this, do:***

```
man limits.conf
google: limits.conf pam setup ulimit change
```

to change the values in `/etc/security/limits.d/nnn-username.conf`

Answer (score 1):

It certainly hasn't anything to do with `mongoid` since that isn't even a driver, so it doesn't even connect to your db-instance.
Furthermore, I'ld recommend you to post your log-files at https://jira.mongodb.org/.
(but feel free to add some more info to your question, so we may be able to help you here =).)

Comment: tim, I selected mongoid tag just to inform that is a rails application, thanx =)

Comment: Okay. Still, could you please add some more info? We aren't able to help you with this. For example: how long *does* it run before it quits, have it ever been working, etc.

Comment: this problem is related to run on 32bits :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually 32 bit supports data till 2GB of data if you want to store more than that then upgrade to 64 bit. If your data storage is less than 2GB in 32 bit then try **~$ mongod --repair** to solve the unclean shutdown probelm.